# MySQL sub-query listing information on one line

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am trying to get a query to show all the data for event prizes on one line. For example this is an example of my table.

```
Event_id    Place    Money
101         1        120
101         2        60
101         3        30
102         1        100
102         2        50
102         3        25
```

What I want is for the results to look like the following:

```
Event_id    First    Second    Third
101         120      60        30
102         100      50        25
```

Any help to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT    Event_ID,
          GROUP_CONCAT(IF(place = 1, `money`, NULL)) `First`,
          GROUP_CONCAT(IF(place = 2, `money`, NULL)) `Second`,
          GROUP_CONCAT(IF(place = 3, `money`, NULL)) `Third`
FROM      tableName
GROUP BY  event_id
```

If you want learn more about sql tricks, visit this:

[**Common but Useful MySQL Queries**](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php)

[**SEE on SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22dcb/1)

Answer (score 0):

This also works for me

```
SELECT DISTINCT Event_id, (SELECT Money FROM PRIZE WHERE Place=1 AND Event_id=t.Event_id) AS First,
(SELECT Money  FROM PRIZE WHERE Place=2 AND Event_id=t.Event_id) AS Second,
(SELECT Money FROM PRIZE WHERE Place=3 AND Event_id=t.Event_id) AS Third
FROM PRIZE t;
```

Comment: What is difference between previous answer and your answer? is it better than previous?